# Autocomplete has stopped working on list item forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, form, list-item

Just this week one of my users noticed that the autocomplete capability has stopped working on inputs for list item forms.  All of the previous values that she'd been able to use to quickly enter in her list items have disappeared.  Even when she enters new items it doesn't allow autocomplete for ones that she had just entered.  Also, this has happened at the same time to other users who use the same form.  I've even tried it with both Google Chrome and Internet Explorer on my own computer and I experience the same issue.

[image: Autocomplete not working]

After reading up on autocomplete it sounds like a "name" attribute is required in order for it to work.  When I use Chrome Developer tools to investigate one of the input tags I can see that there is no "name" attribute.

Did Microsoft update SharePoint Online and stop using the "name attribute on list item forms?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Per my knowledge, SharePoint provides autocomplete function only for the OOB People and Group control and metadata field in SharePoint. It does not work on the text box.

The autocomplete function you mentioned is provided by the browser, not by SharePoint.

For more information about autocomplete function of browser:

https://support.iclasspro.com/hc/en-us/articles/218569268-How-to-Disable-and-Clear-AutoFill-Info-in-your-Browser

I have reproduced your issue in modern experience. It works in classic experience, but it does not work in modern experience. The modern experience is a new feature and is in the improving phase. It seems that the browser autocomplete function cannot work on the SharePoint modern experience currently.

As a workaround, use the classic experience.

Comment: I am aware that the autocomplete is a function of the browser but it had been working with the "modern" experience for my users up until recently in multiple browsers and so I'm assuming that Microsoft changed the underlying html recently.  In any case thank you for reproducing and verifying my issue.

Comment: The modern experience is in the improving. As a workaround, you can use the classic experience. Or, build own add-on.